# show selected value from dropdown

Tags: php, select, drop-down-menu, echo

Hi i have been working on a form wherein there's a dropdown menu and it's values are from the database. My problem is it doesnt show the value selected after submitting the form. what maybe the problem?

```
<select name="professional" />
        <option value="">Choose one</option>
            <?php 
                $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM professional");
                while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
                {
                    $prc = $row2['name'];
                    $prof = $row2['prcno'] ."\t"."|\t".  $row2['name'] ."\t"."|\t".$row2['profession'];
                    echo "<option value ='$prc'>$prof</option>";
                }

            ?>
        </select>
```

---

```
        <select name="professional" disabled/>
            <option value="">Choose one</option>
            <?php 
                $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM professional");
                $i=0;
                while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
                {
                    $prc = $row2['name'];
                    $p1[$i] = $prc;
                    $prof = $row2['prcno'] ."\t"."|\t".  $row2['name'] ."\t"."|\t".$row2['profession'];
                    $p2[$i] = $prof;
                    if($_POST['professional'] == $p1[$i])
                    {
                        echo "<option selected value ='$p1[$i]'>$p2[$i]</option>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<option value ='$p1[$i]'>$p2[$i]</option>";
                    }

                }

            ?>
        </select>
```

Comment: does your form element have `method="post"`

Comment: What is the content of `$_POST['professional']`? It's empty in the landing page?

Comment: use print_r and debug your code line by line, you will get the solution. First print_r the value of $result2 then $row2 then $prc then $_POST

Comment: what print_r? i dont know how to use it

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: are you sure both have same value $_POST['professional'] == $p1[$i]

Comment: use `print_r($_POST['professional']);` and `print_r($p1[$i]);` before your if statement.

Comment: if `$_POST['professional']` is empty, maybe your problem is in the code of the form page.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, you're not incrementing $i, so you keep overwriting $p1[0] and $p2[0] in each iteration of the while-loop.

So add $i++ at the beginning or the end of your loop - or drop the whole use of these to arrays ($p1 and $p2) and use $prc and $prof just as you do in the first code-block - or do you need them for something?

Another thing, try removing the space between *value* and *='$p1[$i]'* - but I'm not sure if that's a problem.

Comment: how will i increment?

Comment: as i wrote - add in your while-loop (either at the beginning or the end of it) the following line:

        `$i++;`

Which would be the same as:

        `$i += 1;`

or

        `$i = $i + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Try
`selected="selected"`

in stead of

```
selected
```

Comment: It is not required: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-empty

Comment: In if condition, this line:  echo "<option selected value ='$p1[$i]'>$p2[$i]</option>";

Answer (score 0):

change these lines to

```
echo "<option selected value ='<?php echo $p1[$i]; ?>'><?php echo $p2[$i]; ?></option>";
```

and do not forget to **increment your $i** too

**Hope it will help** :)

Comment: how will i increment?

Comment: add $i++; just before closing your while loop

Comment: 'else
{
echo "<option value ='<?php echo $p1[$i]; ?>'><?php echo $p2[$i]; ?></option>";
} **$i++;** }'

Comment: have you saved the file with ".html.php" (together) extension??

Comment: remove the '<?php echo' line i told you and save the file with **filename.html.php** extension..