# echo the selected value from the dropdown menu?

Tags: php, select, drop-down-menu, echo

I have a form and here is code for the dropdown menu. Can you help me make a code to show the selected value after submitting the form? im using php

```
<select name="professional" />
            <option value="">Choose one</option>
                <?php 
                    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM professional");
                    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
                    {
                        $prc = $row2['name'];
                        $prof = $row2['prcno'] ."\t"."|\t".  $row2['name'] ."\t"."|\t".$row2['profession'];
                        echo "<option value ='$prc'>$prof</option>";
                    }

                ?>
            </select>
```

Comment: use $_POST['professional'] on the page which u describe in form action=""; DONT USE THIS -> "SELECT * FROM" select only required values..

Comment: @Ashish The first part is correct, the second is not. That is just populating the select.

Comment: possible duplicate of [show selected value from dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953856/show-selected-value-from-dropdown)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo $_REQUEST['professional'];
?>
```

you might wish to use $_GET or $_POST instead of $_REQUEST, please check: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php